# want to insert multidimensional array value into php database with unique value

Tags: php, arrays

I have one multidimensional-array and i want to insert into my database, there is one issue if one entry in my database and same entry is on my multidimensional-array that value should not insert again in my database.

```
$activity[] = array('user_id'=> $_SESSION['user_id'], 'choosen_date' => $ch_date, 'distance' => $distance, 'pace' => $pace );

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 1200
            [choosen_date] => 2018-12-11
            [distance] => 1.72
            [pace] => 12.4812
        )
[1] => Array
    (
        [user_id] => 1200
        [choosen_date] => 2018-12-09
        [distance] => 3.17
        [pace] => 3.8736
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [user_id] => 1200
        [choosen_date] => 2018-11-14
        [distance] => 2.26
        [pace] => 6.3504
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [user_id] => 1200
        [choosen_date] => 2018-11-07
        [distance] => 0.53
        [pace] => 3.6576
    )

)
```

And following is my database entry

```
----------------------------------------------------
| S.No | user Id | choose date | distance |  Pace  |
----------------------------------------------------
|  1   |  1200   | 2018-12-09  |   3.17   | 3.8736 |
----------------------------------------------------
|  2   |  1200   | 2018-12-11  |   2.17   |  5.67  |
----------------------------------------------------
```

so here, in database S.no 1 and array index 1 both are the same entry so I want to insert rest value into my database. So how can I insert?

Comment: What kind of database do you use?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to do it through PHP then you can try this.

```
$i=0;
foreach($activity as $key=>$val)
{
  $sn_check=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id FROM table WHERE S.No='$i'");
  if(mysqli_num_rows($sn_check)==0)
  {
     $user_id=$val[$i]['user_id']; //all other values can be catch like this.
     $query_insert=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT QUERY");
  }
$i++;
}
```

Comment: You can query for S.No like this :
$sn_start=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT S.No FROM table ORDER BY S.No LIMIT 1"); //this will give you the starting of S.no
$i=$sn_start;

Comment: $user_id=$val[$i]['user_id']; try changing this to :
$user_id=$val[$i].user_id;

Comment: It is now print user_id four times.

Comment: Kindly post your complete code here. Then only I will be able to help.

Comment: $myactivity[] = array('user_id'=> $_SESSION['user_id'], 'choosen_date' => $ch_date, 'distance' => $distance, 'pace' => $pace );
In this variable, i am storing my value which will be save on my database.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201653/discussion-between-santosh-khatri-and-prabhjot-singh-kainth).

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using MySQL database, you can use [INSERT IGNORE INTO](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-ignore/)

or [INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: Thanks dear, i "check insert ignore into" it will work for me or not.

Comment: INSERT IGNORE INTO is not working for me, It is inserting same value.